# How to align text in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do I put an `h1` in the center of an HTML canvas, with either JS or HTML?

I already have a `canvas.js` file.

HTML

```html
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="canvas.js"></script>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

How do I do this?

**Canvas.js includes a small animation, which covers the entire canvas.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to align it both vertically and horizontally:

```
canvas_context.textBaseline = 'middle';
canvas_context.textAlign = "center";
```

Comment: then how do I add text?

Comment: please provide a minimal working example of your script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
<canvas></canvas>
<script type="module" src="canvas.js"></script>
<h1 align="center">Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Hard to say with the video component, but for a pure HTML element it should

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`context.font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) and use [`context.fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"), context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = '700 32px "Times New Roman"';
context.fillText("Hi", (canvas.width / 2) - 20, (canvas.height / 2) + 5);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    h1 { 
        text-align:center; 
    } 
</style>
```

This style, which has to be put in the `<head>` tag, has effect to every `h1` taf.. If you want it more localized, for a specific h1 element, then it can also be applied locally with:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center"> content < /h1>
```